# How to mute ALL notification-sounds (e.g. notification-sound during emptying the trash bin)?

Tags: notification, ubuntu-studio, plasma-5, mute, sound-theme

I just upgraded my Ubuntu Studio system from version 20.04 LTS to 22.04.1 LTS, and suddenly I hear different sounds during events like emptying the trash bin for example, which never happened in my two previous Ubuntu Studio installations 20.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS.

Looking into 'Systemsettings' I cannot find any tab to mute all these annoying notification-sounds. There is no such tab as 'Sounds'? I can only find the tab 'Audio', but nothing to further mute these notification-sounds.

I'm a beginner and need an easy solution, if possible.

--

Thanks and kindest regards

Novice

---

System informations:

- Linux/KDE Plasma: Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.6
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
- Qt Version: 5.15.3

---

SOLUTION:

1. Go to Systemsettings > Hardware > Audio > Playbackstreams (Wiedergabestreams) > Notification-Sound (Benachrichtigungsklang)
2. Klick on the speaker icon to change the default setting from mute to unmute.
3. Raise the volume from 0 to 150 % (don’t know, if this was really necessary).
4. Klick on the speaker icon to change this setting once again, now back from unmute to mute.
5. Restart/reboot system (don’t know, if this was really necessary)

Et voilà, with my speakers turned on no more notification-sound audible, e.g. during emptying the trash bin.

This BUG should be reported!

Thank you 'emetsipe'!

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please don't edit the question. Post an answer if the existing answer doesn't contain the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these should solve your problem:

1. [mute from settings](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-alert.html.en)
2. terminal command [`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false`](https://fostips.com/disable-alert-sound-ubuntu/)
3. (as also seen above) [using dconf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444681/how-to-turn-off-alert-sounds-sound-effects-on-gnome-from-terminal?rq=1)
4. [this accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213285/how-to-disable-event-sounds-in-plasma-5) describes a situation where noitifications are muted like the one you described, try "solving the bug" as shown.
5. [This Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ManjaroLinux/comments/w6s1aj/disable_all_system_sounds_kde_plasma/) says

> You can either remove "oxygen sounds" from add/remove software, or just go into settings/notifications/applications/configure then go through the apps one by one and see which one has "configure events" and uncheck all the sound boxes

Comment: 1. Neither can I find 'Activities' nor 'GNOME': Terminal '$ gnome-session can not be found'.

2./3. Terminal '... dconf-WARNING ... unable to open file ...'.

Comment: Then, I did further research and found that there is apparently no GNOME-Desktop in the current UbuntuStudio 22.04 version, but KDE Plasma Desktop:
https://ubuntustudio.org/
Quote: 'Ubuntu Studio uses the Plasma Desktop by KDE'.

Comment: On this page ...
https://apps.kde.org/de/
... I found KMix with 'Event Sounds', that looked promising:
https://cdn.kde.org/screenshots/kmix/kmix.png

I installed and opened KMix. But unfortunately, there are no adjustments for 'Event Sounds' visible at all. Either the picture (.../kmix.png) is wrong or the installation is faulty. I got in touch with the developers of KMix and was told 'Ignore kmix. It's not what you want. Go to Systemsettings > Hardware > Audio. There you can disable 'Notification Sounds''.

Comment: System Settings -> Hardware -> Audio -> 'Notification Sound' ('Benachrichtigungsklang') is/was already muted by default after the upgrade to UbuntuStudio 22.04.1. However, notification/event sounds are STILL audible, when the speakers are turned on. The notification/event sounds are NOT audible, when the speakers are turned off. But turning the speakers off is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: After that, I had a look for soundfiles on my system and there are plenty located in ...

SYS_UBUSTUD2004 > usr > share > sounds

Among others I found in this folder an audiofile named 'Oxygen-Sys-Trash-Emptied.ogg', that I use as an example/reference. But neither can I delete nor rename this folder 'sounds' respectively the .ogg-audiofile(s), because 'Delete' and 'Rename' in the Contextmenue are greyed out.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: I added a new source, please check it out

Comment: also try to get your KDE Plasma version please

Comment: Reading source #4 newly mentioned by 'emetsipe' was very helpful. With this information in mind I was able to solve the problem. Here is what I did …

Comment: SOLUTION:

1. Systemsettings > Hardware > Audio > Playbackstreams (Wiedergabestreams) > Notification-Sounds (Benachrichtigungsklang)

2. Klick on the speaker icon to change the default setting from mute to unmute.

3. Raise the volume to max. (= 150 %).

4. Klick on the speaker icon to change the setting again now from unmute to mute.

5. System restart (don’t know, if this was necessary)

Et voilà, with my speakers turned on no more notification-sound audible during emptying the trash bin.

Comment: System Informations:
Linux/KDE Plasma: UbuntuStudio 22.04.1 LTS
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.6
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3

Thank you very much for your time and competent help, 'emetsipe' – very appreciated!

There should be a BUG-report for this basic problem!

Comment: yesterday I stumbled upon a bug report page and that's when I asked for your KDE version since there were a couple of similar problems but regardin different versions, but I didn't save the address.